# AFNetworking - How to make POST request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking

**EDIT 07/14**

*As Bill Burgess mentionned in a comment of his answer, this question is related to the `version 1.3` of `AFNetworking`. It may be outdated for the newcomers here.*

---

I'm quite new to iPhone development, and I'm using AFNetworking as my services library.

The API i'm querying is a RESTful one, and I need to make POST requests. To do this, I tried with the following code :

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my_username", @"username", @"my_password", @"password", nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/login"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Pass Response = %@", JSON);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Failed Response : %@", JSON);
}];
[operation start];
```

There are two main issues with this code :

- `AFJSONRequestOperation` seems to make a `GET` request, not a `POST` one.
- I can't put parameters to this method.

I also tried with this code :

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"my_username", @"username", @"my_password", @"password", nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

[httpClient postPath:@"/login" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Succes : %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure : %@", error);
}];
```

Is there a better way to make what I want here to get it done ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can override the default behavior of your request being used with `AFNetworking` to process as a POST.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil];
```

This assumes you have overridden the default `AFNetworking` setup to use a custom client. If you aren't, I would suggest doing it. Just create a custom class to handle your network client for you.

**MyAPIClient.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface MyAPIClient : AFHTTPClient

+(MyAPIClient *)sharedClient;

@end
```

**MyAPIClient.m**

```
@implementation MyAPIClient

+(MyAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static MyAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webAddress]];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}

-(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    return self;

}
```

Then you should be able to fire off your network calls on the operation queue with no problem.

```
    MyAPIClient *client = [MyAPIClient sharedClient];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myapipath/?value=%@", value];
    NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:nil];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // code for successful return goes here
        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];

        // do something with return data
    }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        // code for failed request goes here
        [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];

        // do something on failure
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: Thank for your reply ! Just one question : your `SIOAPIClient ` would be a `MyAPIClient` here no ?

Comment: You are right... I copy/pasted this from my own implementation and changed the class names around. Missed a spot I guess. I edited my answer to how it should be.

Comment: I tried to implement a custom client just as you're writing, but I get an error : `No known class method for selector 'sharedClient'`. The header is included correctly, so I wonder why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I added the information for the header that might help resolve this.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to add the method in the .h file... thanks for the edit !

Comment: One last thing : I have the right JSON response, but it seems that the code from the "failure" block is executed. Any idea of where does this come from ?

Comment: In the error, I get : `"Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/plain"`

Comment: You may need to play with that header setup. My example has it set up as "application/json". And it seems to work good for me. Check your server configuration and set it up however it needs to be to pull the data back correctly.

Comment: It's OK. i modified the `AFJsonRequestOperation.m` to also accept `text/plain`, waiting for my server to send my proper `application/json` response.

Comment: @Bill Burgess, I need to pass username and password combinedly but we have only method like  [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"" password:@""]; any idea?

Comment: This is something you would probably need to add when you override and create your custom client. You would need to set the headers there. If you are trying to use some sort of OAuth client, this may not work for you. There are other questions/answers that will detail how to handle OAuth. This is just for basic stuff.

Comment: 'self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;' Helped me send post data as JSON instead of URL parameters

Comment: Where's the definition of AFHTTPClient.h? When I downloaded the AFNetworking Folder, it's not included there.

Comment: This answer is likely out of date now with the latest versions of AFNetworking. When this answer was created, it was for AFNetworking 1.3 or so.