# AFNetworking Always Fails

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

I have this standard AFNetworking Method

[self postPath:@"/signup/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

It always fails. Always.

What do I need to do to get it to pass. What should the backend server return to the app so that this passes?

Flask/Django preferably or just explain the concept if you are not familiar with Python

At the moment using flask
I have tried
1. returning a JSON representation of the user
2. returning a 200 response and no content

None of these seem to work.

What should I do?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918839/create-user-method-is-failing)?

Comment: It is similar, I just broke it down into a smaller chunk, since nobody answered the full scale problem, I thought this might be easier to answer.

Comment: If you want better answers, you should explain what "It always fails" means, in as much detail as you can. (Do you get a response at all? If so, what's in it? Is there an error code? Are you sure you're talking to your server, and if so, what data is it sending back? Do you get any errors in the logs in the server? etc.)

Comment: Or this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914577/user-login-with-afnetworking

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example from one of my older projects (AFNetworking and JSON-response):

```
- (void) loadItems:(NSString*)searchText
{
    NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/index.php?s=%@", searchText];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:surl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]]; //content-type is not set properly by the server
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                NSLog(@"Done: %@", JSON);                
            }
            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                NSLog(@"failure: %@", [error description]);
            }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Hope this helps.

You can also check this answer for POST-requests:
[AFNetworking - How to make POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294769/afnetworking-how-to-make-post-request)